# Angularjs role based routing error

Tags: angularjs, permissions, authorization, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to implement role based authorization in [beeman's loopback-angular-admin](https://github.com/beeman/loopback-angular-admin) repo by using this https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission

so I am trying to change the `users.config.js` to like this -

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('com.module.users')
    .run(function ($rootScope, gettextCatalog, Permission, AppAuth, User) {
      $rootScope.addMenu(gettextCatalog.getString('Users'), 'app.users.list', 'fa-user');
      Permission.defineRole('anonymous', function (stateParams) {
        // If the returned value is *truthy* then the user has the role, otherwise they don't
        return !AppAuth.hasOwnProperty('currentUser');
      });
      Permission.defineRole('student', function (stateParams) {
        // If the returned value is *truthy* then the user has the role, otherwise they don't
        AppAuth.ensureHasCurrentUser(function () {
          //This call also serves to redirect a user to the login screen, via the interceptor in users.auth.js, if they are not authenticated.
          console.log(User.getCurrent());
          return !!(User.getCurrent().hasOwnProperty('role') && User.getCurrent().role == 'student');
        });
      }).defineRole('tutor', function (stateParams) {
        // If the returned value is *truthy* then the user has the role, otherwise they don't
        AppAuth.ensureHasCurrentUser(function () {
          //This call also serves to redirect a user to the login screen, via the interceptor in users.auth.js, if they are not authenticated.
          console.log(User.getCurrent());
          return !!(User.getCurrent().hasOwnProperty('role') && User.getCurrent().role == 'tutor');
        });
      });
    });

})();
```

So basically I am defining my roles with the help of AppAuth module that has the following code -

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  /*jshint sub:true*/
  /*jshint camelcase: false */

  angular
    .module('com.module.users')
    .factory('AppAuth', function ($cookies, User, LoopBackAuth, $http) {
      var self = {
        login: function (data, cb) {
          LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = null;
          $http.post('/api/users/login?include=user', {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password
          })
            .then(function (response) {
              if (response.data && response.data.id) {
                LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = response.data.userId;
                LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = response.data.id;
              }
              if (LoopBackAuth.currentUserId === null) {
                delete $cookies['accessToken'];
                LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = null;
              }
              LoopBackAuth.save();
              if (LoopBackAuth.currentUserId && response.data && response.data
                  .user) {
                self.currentUser = response.data.user;
                cb(self.currentUser);

              } else {
                cb({});
              }
            }, function () {
              console.log('User.login() err', arguments);
              LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId =
                null;
              LoopBackAuth.save();
              cb({});
            });
        },

        logout: function (cb) {
          //Destroy the access token.
          User.logout({"access_token": LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId}, function () {
            //Destory both cookies that get created.
            delete $cookies["access_token"];
            delete $cookies["accessToken"];
            //Perform the Passport Logout
            $http.post('/auth/logout');

          });
          self.currentUser = null;
          cb();
        },

        ensureHasCurrentUser: function (cb) {
          if ((!this.currentUser || this.currentUser.id === 'social') && $cookies.accessToken) {
            LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = null;
            $http.get('/auth/current')
              .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.id) {
                  LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = response.data.id;
                  LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = $cookies.accessToken.substring(
                    2, 66);
                }
                if (LoopBackAuth.currentUserId === null) {
                  delete $cookies['accessToken'];
                  LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId = null;
                }
                LoopBackAuth.save();
                self.currentUser = response.data;
                var profile = self.currentUser && self.currentUser.profiles &&
                  self.currentUser.profiles.length && self.currentUser.profiles[
                    0];
                if (profile) {
                  self.currentUser.name = profile.profile.name;
                }
                cb(self.currentUser);
              }, function () {
                console.log('User.getCurrent() err', arguments);
                LoopBackAuth.currentUserId = LoopBackAuth.accessTokenId =
                  null;
                LoopBackAuth.save();
                cb({});
              });
          } else {
            if(self.currentUser){
              console.log('Using cached current user.');
            }
            cb(self.currentUser);
          }
        }
      };
      return self;
    });

})();
```

and then in my routes file I am doing -

```
$stateProvider
        .state('router', {
          url: '/router',
          template: '<div class="lockscreen" style="height: 100%"></div>',
          controller: 'RouteCtrl'
        })
        .state('error', {
          url: '/error',
          template: '<div class="text-center alert alert-danger" style="margin: 100px">An error occurred.</div>'
        })
        .state('app', {
          abstract: true,
          url: '/app',
          templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/app.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          data: {
            permissions: {
              only: ['admin', 'student']
            }
          }
        })
        .state('app.home', {
          url: '',
          templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
          data: {
            permissions: {
              only: ['admin', 'student']
            }
          }
        })
        .state('tutor', {
          abstract: true,
          url: '/tutor',
          templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/app.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          data: {
            permissions: {
              only: ['admin', 'tutor']
            }
          }
        })
        .state('tutor.home', {
          url: '',
          templateUrl: 'modules/core/views/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
          data: {
            permissions: {
              only: ['admin', 'tutor']
            }
          }
        });
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/router');
```

but now I am getting the following error in the browser console -

```
Error: undefined role or invalid role validation
    at Object.Permission._findMatchingRole (angular-permission.js:170)
    at Object.Permission.resolveIfMatch (angular-permission.js:211)
    at Object.Permission.authorize (angular-permission.js:239)
    at angular-permission.js:45
    at Scope.$broadcast (angular-scenario.js:24081)
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3229)
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular-ui-router.js:2346)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4185)
    at handleIfMatch (angular-ui-router.js:1836)
    at angular-ui-router.js:1891
```

so how can I debug this error or implement client side role based authorization in my loopback app

Answer (score 0):

> [..] implement client side role based authorization in my loopback app

This doesn't mean anything, loopback is your server application.

Client-side authorization should be prohibited, since clients can be tampered with.

Authorization should take place server-side exclusively. Client-side you should just adapt the content in function of the role. That way if someone tampers with your client code at least its http requests to the API will fail and your data is safe

Comment: I am doing server side authorisation but I want to create separate views for different type of roles for each module